# Static class fields in Chapel

Tags: static, chapel

Does Chapel have the equivalent of the C++/Java static class field whose value is shared between class objects? If not, what should one do?

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow**. You may've already read StackOverflow Community practice to publish, best MCVE-formulated, problems in Questions, that are **M**inimal (i.e.focused right on spot,having no other parts but those,that demonstrate the Problem-under-Review) that are **C**omplete, that are **V**erifiable **E**xample of the problem, so that it permits to run, modify, test, refactor and compare any and all such possible approaches to the Problem-under-Review solution. **Feel free to re-read details about this Site-rules and update your post** with the **MCVE**-code to let others help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapel does not support an equivalent of static class fields. However, it does support an equivalent of static class methods, referred to as [type methods](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/language/spec.html#class-methods) in Chapel.

If one needed static class fields in Chapel, they could use a parentheses-less method returning a globally defined variable for a similar effect, e.g.

```
var globalValue = 42;

class C {
  var a = 1;

  proc b {
    return globalValue;
  }
}

var c1 = new owned C(1);
var c2 = new owned C(2);

writeln(c1.a);
writeln(c1.b);

writeln(c2.a);
writeln(c2.b);

globalValue += 1;

writeln(c1.a);
writeln(c1.b);

writeln(c2.a);
writeln(c2.b);
```

Output:

```
1
42
2
42
1
43
2
43
```

Comment: Adding to Ben's comment, I think it would be perfectly reasonable to file a feature request against Chapel to support the equivalent of a C++/Java static class field if that was of interest: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues

I also wanted to mention that there's an existing request for the equivalent of local static variables, which would make Ben's solution more attractive by removing the need for a global variable: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/12281